# Why head in linked list is declared as pointer? When while traversing we can define pointer and assign the address of head to it?

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node head;
struct node temp;
struct node *ptr;

head.data = 10;
head.next = NULL;
ptr = &head;

temp.data = 20;
temp.next = NULL;
ptr->next = &temp;
```

is head.next pointing to temp now, like it would when I would have taken head and temp as pointers and allocated memory to them using malloc? What is happening in the above.

Comment: head.next is not pointing to temp, temp is being assigned to next, we can't see how next is declared, but it's suppose to be a pointer to a node... so you need to do something like: ptr->next=&temp; or define temp as a pointer.

Comment: @danielfranca edited!

Comment: head is not declared as a pointer but ptr is. ptr takes the address of head because you have to see ptr like an iterator (ptr moves through elements of your list). Next thing : `\0` is last char of a string. Don't use it for pointer, use `NULL` instead.

Comment: If the above code is in a function, when that function ends, so does the list. 1) Typos: `.next='\0';` (should be simply 0 (or `NULL`)). 2) Does the new C standard allow declarations after other statements? 3) For this example you don't need `ptr`. As for the initial question put it like this: from within a node, the next node in the list is referenced as a pointer to the struct (`NULL` if there is no node). Same thing if you were _before_ the 1st node: the 1st node will be referenced a pointer to the struct (by convention named `head`).

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you want to have a means for representing an empty list.  That means there might not be any first data-bearing node, and the usual way to represent that is to access that node via a pointer when it exists, with that pointer being `NULL` if there are no data-bearing nodes.

It can be convenient to use a dummy, non-data-bearing head node for your list, which could be declared directly rather than being allocated dynamically.  The primary purpose of such a node is to house the pointer to the first data-bearing node, with the advantage of reducing or eliminating special cases in handling the first (real) element of the list.  The same approach can be useful, for the same reasons, for doubly-linked and circular lists.

**Example:**

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *insert_after(struct node *after, int value)  {
    // We can rely on 'after' being non-NULL because we assume there is a
    // dummy head node.
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(new_node));

    if (new_node) {
        new_node->data = value;
        new_node->next = after->next;
        after->next = new_node;
        // inserting at the beginning is not a special case
        return new_node;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

void delete_after(struct node *after) {
    // We can rely on 'after' being non-NULL because we assume there is a
    // dummy head node.
    struct node *to_delete = after->next;

    if (to_delete) {
        after->next = to_delete->next;
        free(to_delete);
        // deleting the first or only element is not a special case
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // not a pointer:
    struct node head = { 0, NULL };  // dummy head node
    struct node *first = insert_after(&head, 42);

    if (first) {
        insert_after(first, 17);
    }
    delete_after(&head);
}
```